# add decimal.Decimal to sqlite3 database

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I know the problems with converting decimals to floats and vice versa. At the moment, I have a program that runs nearly always using the `decimal` module, but when I try to add any `decimal.Decimal` data type into my database it throws the error:

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Here is the code:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = db.cursor()

c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test1 (decimal REAL)')

a = Decimal(2.14) - Decimal(1.55)

c.execute("INSERT INTO test1(decimal) VALUES(?)",(a,))
db.commit()
```

but if I change `Decimal` to `float` it will work.

1. will this affect the accuracy of the answers (I'm pretty sure it does)?
2. is there a better way of doing this than to convert to float in order to store in database? If I can't store it directly in `Decimal` type, than I will need to be able to convert it back to `Decimal` after pulling it from my database.

   3. Why doesn't the "DECIMAL" data type work for this? what am I missing here?

Comment: One option would be to store the *string representation* of the decimal in the database, as you're correct that converting to and from float will mean loss of precision.

Comment: Thank you, let me give this a shot now. I appreciate your time

Comment: Simple and elegant, Idk what I didn't think of that. I guess I felt like it would've been improper, now that I know its normal to do this it makes it much more simple. Thank you Jon, I appreciate your time! Have a great day.